# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel' after installing babel

Tags: python

As the question says I installed babel from my command prompt

> pip install babel

(I also did pip3 install babel) and it just says "Requirement already satisfied" but when I run my code it prints out the Error I mentioned

Comment: Please copy the exact output of your terminal / shell / IDE. My guess is that you have python 2 and python 3 installed, and you just use the wrong version accidentally.

Comment: You will have to find the various installation that you have on **your** system, because we cannot do... More seriously, if you launch your script with `python script.py ...` you should use the same python interpretor for pip with `python -m pip install babel` (replace `python` by the actual command that you use...)